# Three.js Multiple textures and images in one scene

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, three.js

I am using THREE.js to display a 3d rotating earth in the browser. I also want a image to appear around the rotating earth.
I tried using the built in method,

```
var img = new THREE.ImageLoader();
img.load("texture/circle.png");
```

But the image does not appear only. It's just the rotating sphere.

I want something like this

[image]

Here is my script tag,

```
<script>

    var container, stats;
    var camera, scene, renderer;
    var group;
    var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

    var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

    init();
    animate();

    function init() {

    container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
    camera.position.z = 650;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    group = new THREE.Object3D();
    scene.add( group );

    // earth



    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.load( 'textures/land_ocean_ice_cloud_2048.jpg', function ( texture ) {

    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 200, 20, 20 );

    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, overdraw: true } );
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    group.add( mesh );


    } );

    // shadow

    var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
    canvas.width = 128;
    canvas.height = 128;

    var context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
    var gradient = context.createRadialGradient(
    canvas.width / 2,
    canvas.height / 2,
    0,
    canvas.width / 2,
    canvas.height / 2,
    canvas.width / 2
    );
    //gradient.addColorStop( 0.1, 'rgba(210,210,210,1)' );
    //gradient.addColorStop( 1, 'rgba(255,255,255,1)' );

    context.fillStyle = gradient;
    context.fillRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );

    var texture = new THREE.Texture( canvas );
    texture.needsUpdate = true;

    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 300, 300, 3, 3 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, overdraw: true } );

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh.position.y = - 250;
    mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
    group.add( mesh );

    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    stats = new Stats();
    stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
    container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

    document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

    //

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

    }

    function onWindowResize() {

    windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    }

    function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

    mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX );
    mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY );

    }



    function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    render();
    stats.update();

    }

    function render() {

    //camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.05;
    //camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * 0.05;
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );

    group.rotation.y -= 0.003;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

    }


    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plane is horizontal. Remove this line:

```
mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
```

Make sure the gradient is set up the way you want it, e.g.,

```
gradient.addColorStop( 0.9, 'rgba( 210, 210, 210, 1 )' );
gradient.addColorStop( 1, 'rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0 )' );
```

Also, `CanvasRenderer` will have artifacts with intersecting objects.

three.js r.62

Comment: I didn't quite understand it. 
I want a similar looking UI as I have shown in the picture. I have no idea how to get it.

Comment: If you are having additional problems, post a new question and show a live example. Then ask a specific question about it.